# Float two flex items left and one right in one row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox to design my layout. Basically my goal is: move the button "I am a button" all the way to the right end of the flex container, and keep the other two social buttons at the left side of the container.

```
<div class="quote-box quote">

  <h2>This is where the quote text is going to beThis is where the quote text is going to beThis is where the quote text is going to be</h2>
  <p class="quote-writter">Quote writer</p>

  <div class="buttons">
  <span class="my-button"><a href="#" class="get-quote-butt">I am a button</a></span>
  <a href="#" class="tweet-quote-butt"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i>
  <a href="#" class="tumblr-quote-butt"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-tumblr"></i>
  </a>
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.wrapper {
 max-width:750px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display:flex; 
 align-items:center;
 order:1;
 }

 .quote-box {
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  margin:20px;
  padding:20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;

  }
  .quote-box .quote-writter{
   display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
 }
 .quote-box .buttons{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
 }
.quote-box > * {
 flex:1 1 100%;
}
.quote-box .my-button{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 width: 100vh;
 order:3;
}
.quote-box .my-button .get-quote-butt{
 display: flex;
 flex-basis: 300px;
 align-items: center;

}
```

[PLEASE LOOK AT THIS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn6EE.png)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `margin-left:auto`, and then adjust your button.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  order: 1;
}

.quote-box {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.quote-box .quote-writter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.quote-box .buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.quote-box>* {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.quote-box .my-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100vh;
  order: 3;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.quote-box .my-button .get-quote-butt {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="quote-box quote">

  <h2>This is where the quote text is going to beThis is where the quote text is going to beThis is where the quote text is going to be</h2>
  <p class="quote-writter">Quote writer</p>

  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="my-button"><a href="#" class="get-quote-butt">I am a button</a></span>
    <a href="#" class="tweet-quote-butt"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="tumblr-quote-butt"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-tumblr"></i>
  </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/156/)**

Comment: Perfect, thank you. May I ask what is the reasoning behind using margin-left? my assumption was with flexbox less manipulation of margin is needed.

Comment: Yes you are right, flex items treat auto margins a bit differently than when used in a block formatting context.

Comment: And I just found out, the button is not responsive anymore, if the screen size gets smaller the button disappears.

Comment: Remove `width: 100vh;` in `.my-button`class, and adjust you button size with  `width`or `padding`, check this out - https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/157/

Comment: I hope you don't mind my constant questioning. After applying your advice, I was wondering first of all why flex-basis does not apply to get-quote-butt and secondly how can I get same sized buttons for the two social buttons on the left? Since flex gives them only as much as space they need, I can not make them equal sized

Comment: Jesus :)... The first is because the flex basis was removed (no need) (check out my last demo above)..and the second (don´t complicate) why you don´t you give the same size the in the classes (.tweet-quote-butt, .tumblr-quote-butt).